# L2Fwd Application achieved good rate, when using VFs on same port but low rate seen, when sending traffic from VF on 1 port to VF on a different port

Tags: dpdk

**Issue Summary:**

On a dual port 10Gbps NIC card my dpdk application can successfully sustain ~9Gbps traffic on each port ( I receive traffic on 1 port , process and send via the same port. Similar process on 2nd port using 2nd application).

However if my application receives traffic on 1 port and sends it to the 2nd port (internally), and a different application receives traffic on the 2nd port - I can maximum receive only upto 3.4Gbps. Beyond this rate, packets are dropped but imissed count in DPDK statistics are not increased.

**Issue in Detail:**

I’m  running on a server that has an "X710 for 10GbE SFP+ 1572" ethernet controller with 2 ports/ physical functions. I have created 4 virtual functions on each physical function.

Physical function:

```
0000:08:00.0 'Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ 1572' if=ens2f0 drv=i40e unused=vfio-pci *Active*
0000:08:00.1 'Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ 1572' if=ens2f1 drv=i40e unused=vfio-pci *Active*
```

**Machine specification:**

```
CentOS 7.8.2003
Hardware:
    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU L5520  @ 2.27GHz
    L1d cache: 32K, L1i cache: 32K, L2 cache: 256K, L3 cache: 8192K
    NIC: X710 for 10GbE SFP+ 1572
RAM: 70Gb
PCI:
    Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express
    Capabilities: [90] Express (v2) Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s, Width x4,
isolcpu: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
NUMA hardware:
    available: 2 nodes (0-1)
    node 0 cpus: 0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14
    node 0 size: 36094 MB
    node 1 cpus: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15
    node 1 size: 36285 MB
Hugepage: size - 2MB and count - 1024
```

**Model-1(Intra VF):**
Running 2 instances of DPDK l2fwd application namely ApApp1 and ApApp2. ApApp1is bound with 2 VFs  and 2 cores, ApApp2 is bound with 1 VF and 1 core.

[image: Model-1 diagram]

Traffic handling:
App1 receives external traffic on VF-0 and sends it out via VF-1. App2 receives external traffic on VF-2 and sends it out via VF-2 itself.

In this model App1 & App2 together receive 8.8 Gbps and transmit the same without any loss.

**Model-2(inter VF):**
I have modified the l2fwd application App1 to send the external traffic to App2, App2 receives and sends it back to App1 and App1 sends traffic out to the external destination.

[Model-2 diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz46k.png)

Traffic handling:
App1 receives external traffic on VF0 and sends it to App2 via VF1. App2 receives packets on VF2 and sends it out to App1 via VF2 itself. App1 receives packets from App2 on VF1 and sends it out to the external destination via VF0

In this model App1 & App2 together receive only 3.5 Gbps and transmit the same without any loss.

If I try to increase the traffic rate, not all packets sent by App1 were received by App2 and vice versa. Please note that there were no increase in the imissed count at port level statistics. (leading to inference that packets were dropped not because of enough cpu cycles but rather in PCI communication between VFs)

I came across following link https://community.intel.com/t5/Ethernet-Products/SR-IOV-VF-performance-and-default-bandwidth-rate-limiting/m-p/277795

However for me, in case of intra VF communication there is no issue with the throughput.
My limited understanding is the communication between two different Physical Functions would happen via PCI express switch

Is so much deterioration in performance expected(two 10Gbps ports giving throughput  of less than 4 Gbps) and hence do I need to change my design?

Could it be because of some misconfiguration?
Please suggest any pointers to proceed further.

Comment: can you please update 1) DPDK version 2) NIC firmware version 3) is it onboard nic or standalone PCIe card 4) PCIe lane allocated and gen connected with. Can you please confirm in vf are you enabling `veb virtual ethernet bridge, putting the nic is spoof off and trusted mode`. I have to assume you are using isol and high CPU freq too.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Please find the answer - 1) DPDK version 20.11.0 2)NIC firmware version 5.05 0x80002927 1.1313.0 (i40e-2.8.20-k) 3)It is standalone PCIe card. Spoof checking is on and trusted mode is off. we have isolated cpu and CPU freq is in conservative mode

Comment: @sharathshetty thanks for sharing nic and firmware details, this will help. can you please share the remaining information `Can you please confirm in vf are you enabling veb virtual ethernet bridge, putting the nic is spoof off and trusted mode`

Comment: @VipinVarghese We have not enabled the virtual ethernet bridge. Currently spoof checking on and trusted is off.

Comment: @VipinVarghese does it make difference when VEB is enabled in our models? how to figure out if it is bridged or not?

Comment: @sharathshetty, without VEB how are you making packets flow between VF ports of the same NIC port? Because you have single physical port and in the pics you are sending between VEB. right?

Comment: If you were not using VEB (physical PCIe) then you should be using some software based forwarding. But since you have not mentioned any software in the question, I assume you are using VEB.

Comment: can you come online and help me understand your setup and issue? I think something is really missing.

Comment: @sharathshetty can you please update

Comment: @VipinVarghese How can I identify that VEB is enabled? Note that I have not passed any EAL parameter to enable it.  In software, I have simply updated/interchanged the MAC address to reach the appropriate destinations.

Let me know if we can connect and discuss this.

Comment: @sharathshetty  very interesting ` I have simply updated/interchanged the MAC address to reach the appropriate destinations.`, which looks like you are using Kernel Bridge. But the question is marked as DPDK. I am happy to help you, please share google or zoom meet.

Comment: @sharathshetty waiting for you

Comment: @VipinVarghese please let me know your comfortable timing, so that i can setup a google meet event

Comment: I am from India hence IST, comfortable timings were 3-4 hours back. I can make myself available for you around 10PM

Comment: still waiting for the google meet from your end

Comment: Can we meet using the same link on 14 Sep at 11 AM? Please let us know your availability

Comment: @sharathshetty being waiting for you on 14 Sep 2022 10PM. Since today is 15 Sep 2022 still waiting.

Comment: Hi @sharathshetty I have tried couple of times to reach you, looks like you are busy with something. hence not able to make it. No issues, Based on the problem description ` my application receives traffic on 1 port and sends it to the 2nd port (internally), and a different application receives traffic on the 2nd port - I can maximum receive only upto 3.4Gbps.` this looks more like PCIe lane availability issue. Please check the same. Live debug would be much easier for root out these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the analysis of the issue, there seem to be a platform configuration related issue which can cause this effects.

Problem: (Throughput issue) unable to achieve 20Gbps bi-directional (from simulator ingress and application egress via VF) based on `maximum receive only upto 3.4Gbps`.

[Solution] This is most likely to following reason

1. Interconnect cables like fiber, copper, DAC might be faulty. very unlikely for both ports.
2. Both ports might be negotiating to half duplex. Not likely because default settings for DPDK force full duplex.
3. Platform or motherboard not setting the right PCIe gen or allocating sufficient lanes. **Most likely**

To identify the PCIe lane issue use `sudo lscpi -vvvs [PCIe BDF] | gerp Lnk`. Compare for `LnkCap` against `LnkSta`. If there is a mismatch then its a PCIe lane issue.

[Edit based on live debug] it has been identified indeed the issue was PCIe link. The current Xeon platform only support PCIe gen-2 4x lanes, while X710-T2 card requires `PCie gen 3, 4x lanes`.

Recommended in upgrading the CPU and mother board with least Broadwell Xeon or better.